# Grails oauth plugin: unable to create a new calendar event in google

Tags: java, grails, oauth, google-calendar-api

I am using grails Oauth plugin. And I am unable to create a new event in google calendar.

**Service code:**

```
def addNewEvent(String calendarId){
    Token token=getGoogleAccessToken()
    def calendars = oauthService.postGoogleResource(token, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events?key=${grailsApplication.config.oauth.providers.google.key}", [end:'2013-09-26', start: '2013-09-26', summery: 'Testing'])
}
```

**Logs:**

```
signing request: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/vrg3e08emcipgm4772u2iep2h4@group.calendar.google.com/events?key=163071926482.apps.googleusercontent.com
setting token to: Token[1/xxx-xxx , xxx_yyy]
generating signature...
base string is: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fcalendar%2Fv3%2Fcalendars%2Fvrg3e08emcipgm4772u2iep2h4%40group.calendar.google.com%2Fevents&end%3D2013-09-26%26key%3D163df071926482.apps.googleusercontent.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3D1630719264df82.apps.googleusercontent.com%26oauth_nonce%3D254349338721%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1380260738%26oauth_token%3D1%252FSH5y9a8gO4AdG5bG3okN2348bi4tcxYdF-B3TL3jzN1kfw%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fcalendar%26start%3D2013-09-26%26title%3DTesting
signature is: ft/wk6omCDRh2Dk5jhC7NpBK1V4=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> ft/wk6omCDRh23Dk5jhC7NpBK1V4= , scope -> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 2543498721 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> 163071926482.apps.googleusercontent.com , oauth_token -> 1/SH5y9a8gO433AdG5bG3okN8bi4tcxYdF-B3TL3jzN1kfw , oauth_timestamp -> 1380260738 }
using Http Header signature
```

When I make this call via [Google api Explorer](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.insert), it is working.

Can anyone please give me some idea how to create a calendar event or where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried google API console to create a [quick event](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.quickAdd) and it create an event in my calander.
I tried this in sample application.

```
def google() {
    Token token = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('google')]
    def text = "Test Data".encodeAsURL()
    def calendarId = "asd@xyz.com".encodeAsURL()
    def calendars = oauthService.postGoogleResource(token, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events/quickAdd?text=${text}&sendNotifications=true&key=${grailsApplication.config.oauth.providers.google.key}")
    def calendarsJSON = JSON.parse(calendars.body)
    render calendarsJSON.toString()
}
```

Above code successfully create an event with name `Test Data` for one hour in my google calendar.

I am trying to create an event for specific time. I will update this post after creating event successfully.
And these are my logs.

```
signing request: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/abc%xyz.com/events/quickAdd?text=Test+Data&sendNotifications=true&key=28284284224.apps.googleusercontent.com
setting token to: Token[1/bhhuujnin , d7ispjnkjnkSUsX8ckIdVOIH0bLXQa]
generating signature...
base string is: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fcalendar%2Fv3%2Fcalendars%2Fabc%2540xyz.com%2Fevents%2FquickAdd&key%3D28284284224.apps.googleusercontent.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3D28284284224.apps.googleusercontent.com%26oauth_nonce%3D28284284224%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1381555963%26oauth_token%3D1%252Fifa0cTEhk6VRmU_YAQ61pX9Nsvdvsdg8BN7fbAyTKmBlBcIZ7A%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fcalendar%26sendNotifications%3Dtrue%26text%3DTest%2520Data
signature is: TmuhOi8ockEPKdjhjiK5fPMyVJ2wfU=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> TmuhOi8ockEPkhkKdiK5fPMyVJ2wfU= , scope -> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 3332489143 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> 28284284224.apps.googleusercontent.com , oauth_token -> 1/ifa0cTEhk6VRmU_YAQsfgeg_61pX9N8BN7fbAyTKmBlBcIZ7A , oauth_timestamp -> 1381555963 }
using Http Header signature
```

Comment: Can you show the HTTP headers for the request? Was the plugin able to use OAuth 2 for Google API?

Comment: @dmahapatro I did not anything in header. I just write this code to create a quick event.

Comment: Yes but you should have the HTTP header for the request and the logs as shown in the question if you have debug level on in the global providers section in the config. Do you have them available? And were you able to `insert` an `event` as OP has asked for?

Comment: I am not sure how it works because it still uses oauth version 1 to call the API where it should use version 2 for calendar API? Is something missing? The main problem is still open though.

Answer (score 2):

On a first look, `bodyParameters` [as per the api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) looks different. `end` and `start` are nested objects.

Shouldn't you try with the below `bodyParameters`:

```
['end.date':'2013-09-26', 'start.date':'2013-09-26', summary:'Testing']
```

You can also try

```
[end:[date:'2013-09-26'], start:[date:'2013-09-26'], summary:'Testing']
```

Also rectify `summery` with `summary`.

I can look into it in detail if the above is not the reason of discrepancy.

**UPDATE**
I was able to replicate your issue. After digging for a long period of time, found that grails oauth plugin **does not support** Google Oauth 2 API. There has been a [pull request submitted](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/pull/408) for the same.

You can use the changes provided by the pull request or directly use scribe with the latest [Google2Api](https://gist.github.com/yincrash/2465453) as mentioned in [this fork](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) and as [an example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/GoogleExample.java) in detail.

Definitely, the parameter map was an issue, the above setup for end date, start date and summary has to be used. I am looking into it as well to see if I can successfully provide a working example for the same in groovy or as a Grails project in github. I would also see how the pull request affects the plugin. BTW, I tested with `Oauth v2.2.1` plugin.

Hope that helps, will keep this answer updated as and when I proceed further.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is not working. I am still getting error:[error:[message:Invalid Credentials, errors:[[message:Invalid Credentials, location:Authorization, reason:authError, locationType:header, domain:global]], code:401]].

Comment: I am unable to figure out, why with same Credentials I am able to get and delete an event but unable to create and update event.

Comment: How does `getGoogleAccessToken()` look like?

Comment: getGoogleAccessToken() returns :   Token[1/tZMsgXt2pI4T06sU2JSxz2oKsW2uMsmf8Vp-CYZNIRU , caJ952u7Pp6LNdtFVBtlk5x5]

Comment: Can you paste the http request and response. Have you compared the non-working request from your app with the working request from API Explorer to see the difference? That access token looks a bit odd. Also what's with all the signing and nonce stuff? That's oauth1, you should be using oauth2 as it's much simpler and better supported. What scope did you authorise with?